# Set auto brightness

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make a checkbox to control the brightness. Until now able to recognize if the auto brightness is enabled or not but can not turn it off or turn it according to whether it is enabled or not. I wrote this code:

```
private static final String SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE = "Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE";
private static final int SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL = 0;
private static final int SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC = 1; 

try {
        enabled = Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE);
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        enabled = 0;
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } 

    if(enabled==SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL) {

        ((CheckBox)auto).setChecked(false);
        brightbar.setEnabled(true);

        }

        else if(enabled==SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC) {

            ((CheckBox)auto).setChecked(true);
            brightbar.setEnabled(false);

        }

    auto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(enabled==SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL){
                Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
                brightbar.setEnabled(false);
            }else if(enabled==SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC){
                Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
                brightbar.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    });
```

If active mode automatically recognizes that it is turned on, but if I click on the checkbox to disable it does not work, in the sense that it turns it off. Conversely, if the auto brightness is disabled and I click on the checkbox to activate it, it does not work, in the sense that it activates it.

Comment: where have you coded these codes, can you provide us more information.

Comment: I have to publish the entire class?